# Running Steam game in fullscreen doesn't allow second screen to show anything else (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, display, spaces, fullscreen

In Mavericks, when I'm running a full screen game, the second screen can't show desktop (or browser, or anything else.)  My understanding is that Mavericks sets the second screen in a different Space so both can be used.  Am I doing something wrong or is that a wrong understanding?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Steam uses its own full-screen mechanism independent of the system's full-screen option.  Since it's not the typical full-screen provided by OS X, the multiple spaces feature doesn't work here.

Comment: Thanks Jonjesbuzz!  Does this mean similar for other full-screen games?  It's not just with Steam but just about any other game as well--Guild Wars 2, etc.  Does that mean they all override Spaces?

Comment: Yep, if you can't switch Spaces or it blacks out your second monitor, Spaces has been overridden.  Apple's Spaces implementation (for multiple monitors) is more for apps than games.

Comment: Thanks!  And ARGH!  That was for me a big part of getting two monitors!  Danke!